# XMLGregorianCalendar from String error result

Tags: java, xml, date, jaxb

I'm getting a string and trying to convert it to a XMLGregorianCalendar but I'm getting a wrong result.

current code:

```
Flight flight = new flight();

XMLGregorianCalendar result = null;
Date date = null;
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat;
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar;

try {   
    simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");        
    date = simpleDateFormat.parse(flightDate);
    gregorianCalendar = (GregorianCalendar)GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    gregorianCalendar.setTime(date);
    result = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FlightBookings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (DatatypeConfigurationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FlightBookings.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

flight.setDate(result);
```

So my flight object has this attribute:

```
protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
```

and this function to set it:

```
public void setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar value) {
    this.date = value;
}
```

When I then print out the `flight` objects date using this:

```
System.out.println(flight.getDate());
```

I get this:

```
2014-06-04T09:15:00.000+01:00
```

But when I marshall it to an XML document using jaxbm, the value shown in XML is:

```
2014-06-04+01:00
```

The result I want to save to the XML field should look like this:

```
04/06/2014 09:15
```

Any ideas what is going wrong?
Thanks.

UPDATE:

Flight class:

```
public static class Flight {

    @XmlElement(name = "ID")
    protected int id;
    @XmlElement(name = "Origin_City", required = true)
    protected String originCity;
    @XmlElement(name = "Destination_City", required = true)
    protected String destinationCity;
    @XmlElement(name = "Airline", required = true)
    protected String airline;
    @XmlElement(name = "Available_Seats")
    protected int availableSeats;
    @XmlElement(name = "Number_Of_Connections")
    protected int numberOfConnections;
    @XmlElement(name = "Date", required = true)
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
    protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    @XmlElement(name = "Fare", required = true)
    protected FareType fare;
```

Includes all the get and set functions also.

Comment: Post your `Flight` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple mistake. I set the type to just `date` in the XML Schema but should have been `dateTime`. That is why the time was not saved.

Comment: Right here: `@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")` :) Posting code does wonders.